# Why and when is cast to char volatile& needed?

Tags: c++, boost, casting

In [boost::detail::addressof_impl::f()](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/browser/trunk/boost/utility/addressof.hpp#L37) a series of `reinterpret_cast`s is done to obtain the actual address of the object in case `class T` has overloaded `operator&()`:

```
template<class T> struct addressof_impl
{
    static inline T* f( T& v, long )
    {
        return reinterpret_cast<T*>(
            &const_cast<char&>(reinterpret_cast<const volatile char&>(v)));
    }
}
```

What's the purpose of cast to `const volatile char&` instead of just casting to `char&`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A cast straight to `char&` would fail if `T` has `const` or `volatile` qualifiers - `reinterpret_cast` can't remove these (but can add them), and `const_cast` can't make arbitrary type changes.

Answer (score 4):

The object may be `const` or `volatile`, or both (as oxymoronic as that may be), in which case it is probably illegal to `reinterpret_cast` it to a type that lacks these attributes.  (Going in the opposite direction is of course never a problem).

Comment: It's not oxymoronic to be both `const` and `volatile`. For example, a read-only hardware register that gives a different value each time it's read, or a read-only object in shared memory that's updated by another process, should have both qualifiers.

Comment: Yup.  That aspect of const is indeed confluent with volatile.