# Query the alignment of a specific variable

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-alignment

C++11 introduced the [`alignas` specifier](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignas) to specify the alignment of a variable, and the [`alignof` operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignof) to query the default alignment of a type. However, I don't see any way to get the alignment of a specific variable. Let's take the following trivial example:

```
alignas(16) float* array;
```

Here is what we can do about it:

- `alignof(float*)` returns 8, which is obviously not what we want.
- `alignof(array)` returns 16, which is exactly what we want, but that's a compiler extension; `alignof` as specified by the standard can't be used on a specific variable.
- `alignof(decltype(array))` returns 8, which was quite expected but not what we want.
- [`std::alignment_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/alignment_of) is implemented in terms of `alignof`, so it doesn't help much.

I would like a mechanism to confirm that the specific variable `array` is aligned on a 16 byte boundary. Is there anything in the standard to perform such a query?

Comment: *alignof* doesn't need to provide that - it returns a minimum contract at *compile time* - You want a value *at run time*. A specific variable might very well be *aligned to a page boundary*, megabyte-boundaries, or whatever at run time (i.e. much "better" than promised or asked for). Take the address of the variable and check that it is divisible by your wanted alignment value evenly.

Comment: @tofro Right, I forgot to specify it, but I kind of half-expected `alignof` to turn into a runtime thingy when used on a variable name (I guess this is what the compiler extension does). I didn't expect everything to be known at compile-time.

Comment: I can't quite see whether something like *#define ALIGNED8(x) ((&(x) && 0x7) ==  0)* doesn't fit your purpose or why the standard should have something that duplicates this simple construct.

Comment: Do you want to know that actual alignment or the minimal alignment that is guaranteed for a certain variable?

Comment: @MikeMB The obvious use case: known whether the `float` array is suitably aligned to be used with SSE.

Comment: @Morwenn: Maybe I wasn't clear. Its the actual vs. guaranteed part that is important. I'm asking, because the former is a runtime property, that can (on most platforms) simply be determined as shown in the answers or by tofro. The latter however would be a compiletime property and I don't know of any way to retrieve that.

Comment: @tofro maybe you meant `&`, but bitwise-and cannot be used on a pointer

Comment: @MikeMB I... guess I'm interested in the latter? I mean, while we need the array of `float` to be 16 byte aligned, an array of `float` that is 32 byte aligned is also suitable SSE if I'm not mistken.

Comment: @M.M.: The example was not intended as an answer, but rather to deliberately demonstrate *simplicity of a concept*. *reinterpret_cast* is a bit long for a comment. And the && is actually a typo, right.

Comment: @tofro:  Because not all pointers are simply memory addresses.  I have used a machine where that would completely not work (Prime mini-computer.  Word addressed, bit offset in a trailing extension word - but bit offset could only be 0 or 8.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try with something like:

```
bool is_aligned(const volatile void *p, std::size_t n)
{
  return reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(p) % n == 0;
}

assert(is_aligned(array, 16));
```

The above assumes a flat address space and that arithmetic on `uintptr_t` is equivalent to arithmetic on `char *`.

While these conditions prevail for the majority of modern platforms, neither of which is required by the standard.

It's entirely possible for an implementation to perform any transformation when casting `void *` to `uintptr_t` as long the transformation can be reversed when casting back from `uintptr_t` to `void *` (see [What is uintptr_t data type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1845482/3235496)).

Further details in [N4201](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4201.html) (it proposes, among other things, the `is_aligned()` operation).

---

EDIT

> is `volatile` necessary here?

It allows something like:

```
alignas(16) volatile float a;

assert(is_aligned(&a, 16));
```

Without `volatile` you get the error

> no known conversion from 'volatile float *' to 'const void *' for 1st argument

Further references:

- [Why and when is cast to char volatile& needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2333960/3235496)
- [Why is a point-to-volatile pointer, like "volatile int * p", useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9935190/3235496)

Comment: I can see why a standardized function would be useful if it needs those guarantees. N4201 [has been rejected](https://issues.isocpp.org/show_bug.cgi?id=61) though.

Comment: @manlio, is `volatile` necessary here? And if so, shouldn't it be `const void* volatile`?

Comment: @user5434231 I've added some references to the answer

Comment: The cast to `uintptr_t` doesn't have to do any transform for the arithmetic not to work.  Consider the old 8086 address model where a 32-bit address consisted of a 16 bit segment pointer and a 16 bit offset, and the actual physical address was segment<<4 + offset.

Answer (score 7):

This is currently handled by [EWG 98](http://cplusplus.github.io/EWG/ewg-active.html#98). I submitted [a paper](http://arcoth.github.io/Proposals/alignof_objects.html) on this:

> The `alignas` specifier is applicable to objects, affecting their alignment requirement but not their type. It is therefore currently not possible to determine an object's actual alignment requirement. This paper proposes to permit application of `alignof` to objects and references.

The best you can do at this point in time is to define a separate variable holding the variable's alignment.

Comment: I'm glad to see that other people thought about it and started working on it :)

Answer (score 3):

You could try this:

```
template<size_t size, typename T>
constexpr bool IsAlignedAs(const T& v)
{
    return (reinterpret_cast<const size_t>(&v) % size) == 0;
}

std::cout << IsAlignedAs<16>(array) << std::endl;
std::cout << IsAlignedAs<32>(array) << std::endl;
```

Comment: By the way, you could use `static_assert(IsAlignedAs<16>(array), "Array not aligned to 16");` for your array, but you cannot use `static_assert(IsAlignedAs<32>(array), "Array not aligned to 32");` since it is undecided at compile-time whether or not this is true.

Comment: Not a constant expression for clang.

Comment: Indeed it seems gcc specific. Checking the alignment of an address at compile-time (before linking it to its final location) already seemed a bit premature...