# _ADDRESSOF(v) macro definition in VS2019 C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, macros

In `<vadefs.h>` you'll find the following definition for the macro `_ADDRESSOF(v)` in VS2019:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
    #define _ADDRESSOF(v) (&const_cast<char&>(reinterpret_cast<const volatile char&>(v)))
#else
    #define _ADDRESSOF(v) (&(v))
#endif
```

I'd like to understand the first definition above, when `__cplusplus` is defined. Why does it work?

Comment: Since the macro starts with an "_" it's an internal implementation detail of a library. In "C" this returns a pointer to v (address), in C++ it goes through some extra hoops to ensure a  char* to the adress of v succeeds when either v has a volatile or const attribute. (Some more details here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333960/why-and-when-is-cast-to-char-volatile-needed)

Comment: Also see: [`std::addressof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/addressof)

Comment: Also, unlike in C, in C++ some "smart" guy can overload `operator&` for some classes, to return something other than the address. However, type `char` uses the built in operator that cannot be changed.